# Is it fair to reduce OOP to mere hierarchical composition of data structures?

Tags: object-oriented, paradigms, definition

Meaning that OOP allows me to have data-trees, of arbitrary depth and breadth, with some leafs being functions (and those leafs would be called methods) ?

Because everything else that people often put near "OOP" mark, just don't seem to have anything to do with it. (Inheritance, subtype polymorphism and encapsulation seem to be orthogonal to OOP).

Am I right? Or I'm missing something ?

Comment: No, it's not fair, or at least not accurate. Inheritance, polymorphism and encapsulation are three of the major points that define what constitutes OOP. You may not use or care about them, but they're clearly part of what most people understand "OOP" to mean.

Comment: @c69: You should listen to [this guy](https://www.tele-task.de/archive/video/flash/14029/).

Comment: I think any system that allowed a class/interface to inherit/implement more than one parent class/interface might immediately break your "tree" view of things.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner yes! but that blurs the definition even further.. what will remain from OOP, after we throw the trees out, as well ?

Comment: @c69: What will remain? I don't see why anything would be "gone" if "we throw the trees out". Why do you appear to assume that trees were the best structure to start with, in the first place?

Comment: @pillmuncher tnx for the video, but "i wish we made objects bigger back in 70s" and [LoP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language-oriented_programming) are not exactly answering my question. (_But yeah, i agree that OOP is obsolete and sucks, and so on, but that's irrelevant to this discussion_)

Comment: Since encapsulation, polymorphism and inheritance (in that order) is the essence of OOP, I have a hard time understanding why they seem "orthogonal to OOP" to you.

Comment: @arnaud because you don't need OOP (or even OO-capable language) to use them.

Comment: @c69: I would say that inheritance and subtype polymorphism are a good way to define object-orientation (ie, if you are using these in your code then you code is object-oriented, regardless of language). However, I agree with you that "encapsulation" and (plain) "polymorphism" are generic terms and can apply to other things too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it fair to reduce OOP to mere hierarchical composition of data structures?
>   Meaning that OOP allows me to have data-trees, of arbitrary depth and breadth, with some leafs being functions (and those leafs would be called methods) ?

I guess you can choose to look at it that way, but I don't believe it's a particularly useful way to look at it.  Specifically, your use of the word "data" (even if you specifically mention functions in there) seems to reduce OOP to a way to model data (or at least, to a data-centric approach).  In my opinion, this is missing the point.

OOP is a particular way to structure code; both behaviour as well as data.  Its main ideas are the normalisation of behaviour (DRY principle), as opposed to, say, the normalisation of data (as in the relational DB concept), and concepts like encapsulation.  At its simplest, encapsulation is achieved by providing an external interface to classes (your public stuff), and an internal implementation (private / protected stuff).  This is quite different to "traditional" modular programming, since your "module" boundaries are structured completely differently - in the case of OO, each class is a mini-module.

It is also important to note that the concept of encapsulation, in the generic sense, is quite different to a specific implementation of encapsulation.  OOP has a specific way that encapsulation is done, inherently (of course, I'm only referring to the core cases here, not patterns, etc).  Inheritance and polymorphism are much more OOP specific ways to achieve other principles (code reuse being one of them).  I'm not sure I'd lump them in the same sentence as encapsulation, they exist at a slightly different level.

OOP also tends to map quite nicely on to a problem domain, allowing you to model a problem in a way that remains understandable to semi-technical users.

What was the point of going through the above mini OOP discussion?  The above is the best I can do to summarise OOP in a few sentences - it highlights the main points of OOP from the perspective of someone who has worked with the technology for a long time.  I don't think reducing it to a hierarchical composition of data structures does it justice.  We can also reduce it to an array of characters in text files, but it doesn't mean that it captures the essence of the paradigm.

Comment: Accepted for this short sentence: `OOP is a particular way to structure code; both behaviour as well as data. Its main ideas are the normalisation of behaviour (DRY principle), as opposed to, say, the normalisation of data (as in the relational DB concept), and concepts like encapsulation. `

Comment: _Update:_ i think Will Cook gave a nice definition of OOP - http://wcook.blogspot.com/2012/07/proposal-for-simplified-modern.html

Comment: @c69 Yes, I think that's a pretty good definition, although if I were reading that with very little prior knowledge of OOP, I'd be lost :)

Answer (score 6):

You're missing something. Probably several somethings, in fact.

Objects are a powerful means of abstraction. They don't just organize data, they organize code. You could argue that that abstraction isn't necessary, that you could produce equivalent code using purely procedural techniques, but that'd be like arguing that high level languages aren't necessary -- it's perfectly possible to write equivalent code in assembly language. Such arguments may be technically true, but they're completely false from a practical standpoint.

Comment: _i currently code in a mix of functional and oo, and last time i coded procedural (beside shell scripts) was qbasic, but that does not add much to discussion._ With all my deepest respect, please, read the question.

Comment: @c69 Read the question, thanks, and I stand by my answer. There's more to OOP than just structuring data. We could get into the specifics (which you seem to discount), but they mostly boil down to tools for abstraction.

Comment: `There is more to OOP, than just structuring` ? Great - that is exactly, what i'm asking in my question. Could you please elaborate on those _extra things_ ?

Comment: It should be noted that there are alternative ways to organize code, namely functions (or even procedures)

Comment: Objects are not organasing the code. Modules does. Classes just happen to be a poor man's modules substitute in the OOP languages, and therefore all the modules fame unfairly goes to the OOP. And all that OOP stuff would shy in front of any truly decent module system (e.g., as in SML).

Comment: @SK-logic 1) Not all OOP is class-based. 2) The question isn't "what's the best programming paradigm?" but "is OOP nothing more than composition of data structures?"

Comment: @c69 Jerry Coffin said it well in his comment: inheritance, polymorphism, and encapsulation aren't orthogonal to OOP, they're important features of OOP. Each of these provides a kind of abstraction, i.e. a way to think about a problem in simpler terms. If you're thinking about an instance of the class Person as a structure with `name`, `address`, and `phone` fields, you're missing out. Objects let you stop thinking about the data inside the object and think instead in terms of what the object can do.

Comment: @Caleb, non-class based OOP has nothing to do with the code structuring. You've just attributed to OOP something that does not belong to it, so yours answer is not quite relevant to that very question.

Comment: @SK-logic I understand that you're [not a huge OOP fan](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/52618/20011) and that's fine. If you prefer a "truly decent module system," that's fine too. But if you think that OOP doesn't influence code structure, I've got a great many projects that demonstrate otherwise. Sure, it's classes rather than objects themselves that are the modules that contain code -- I used "objects" above simply to avoid the class/object distinction. The point is: OOP provides a way to organize code. If you prefer a different way, fine, but it doesn't change the point.

Comment: @Caleb, again, it is not OOP which structures the code, it is rudimentary support for modules it accidentally provides. All the rest of its methodology is actually destructive and hinders the good architecture. I only object to any attempts of highjacking the fame for the code structuring - it does not belong to OOP at all. It is an accidental property which is not inherent to the OOP but borrowed into it by an accidental resemblance of the modules in most of the typical implementations of the classes.

Answer (score 2):

Any formal language is reducible to graphs, but the fact that a language is a graph or tree is insufficient to define what sort of language you have.

If you are trying to establish that a language as OO, then yes, it is a graph (possibly a tree if there is truly no multiple inheritance) where some nodes are functions, some are data types, etc., but the tree will also adhere to certain rules, such as encapsulated state, polymorphism, and inheritance.  If it does not, it's not OOP.

Comment: State can be encapsulated with closure (or you can make public fields), polymorphism is often nothing more than lexical agreement, and "prefer composition over inheritance" kinda limits the scope of applicability for inheritance abusing patterns, once you leave prison of Java.

Comment: I'm not arguing that any of those items aren't available in other ways.  I'm saying that they are what make an OO language OO.  Without all three, it is not an OO language.  And this has nothing to do with Java--the same was true in Smalltalk, and it is a big part of what differentiates C++ from C.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you are missing that OOP is tighly linked to OOA/D which is about modelling the problem domain in a meaningfull and sustainable way. This leads to considerations of coupling, cohesion, responsibilities, separation of concerns, and in turn considerations of encapsulation, composition, inheritance etc.

Comment: Separation of Concerns is in no way unique to OOA/D/P. Coupling and cohesion should be considered in any other paradigm as well. "Responsibilities" is not even a programming concept in strict sense.. So that leaves only `modeling` as _potential_ object-oriented _feature_.

Comment: I agree these things are not unique to OO. The unique part is exactly the modeling approach. But IMO that modeling approach trickles down through the rest, leading to those things being realized differently with OO than with other paradigms. Btw. I'm not saying OO is necessarily better than other paradigms, just that they differ because of modeling approaches.

Comment: It's quite common to do OOP without OOA/D.  OOA seems to be losing popularity to BDD and TDD.